# kivy service what to write in buildozer.spec

Tags: android, service, kivy

I wrote a service for kivy for android. On the phone, with the help of kivy launcher, **the service starts and works properly**. However, after building the apk file with buildozer (and installing it accordingly), the service starts and stops immediately. do I have to specify something in the buildozer.spec file regarding the service? Or is it somehow different to get the apk file?

Answer (score 0):

i used to face this issue and solved it with a minor hack, i have a not so complete projects that uses this feature to interact with an online database to send some "push" notifications to my kivy app. 
[the link to my repo](https://github.com/mcroni/kivy_gosh.git) ,i hope it helps

Comment: I know your comment is over a year old, but can you just briefly explain to me what you did? I have this same problem and can't seem to solve it

Comment: can you post a log of the problem here, better still send me an email joeydanieldarko@gmail.com

Comment: I don't have a log, but the app crashes when I launch it. This only happens when I start the service

Comment: that would be hard to debug your problem, if you are using the kivy launcher, kindly look into the same folder of your app, you will find a hidden folder with the name log with some txt files, that will do

Comment: I am using a compiled app. The app works perfectly in kivy launcher, but when compiled it failed